# Karate graphql variables inside query

Tags: testing, graphql, automated-tests, karate

I am trying to insert previously defined variable inside graphql query but I'm not able to find any example on how to do that except creating variables outside of query text and then making request with variables.

There is one problem for me for example in this example

```
queries: [{type: TERM, match: EQUAL, field: "fieldOne", value: "#(id)"},
          {type: TERM, match: EQUAL, field: "fieldTwo", value: null}]
```

I want to insert value #(id) only for the first object in graphql query. Can anyone please provide some example for me or any suggestions on how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright I was thinking that it will be possible to directly replace text inside query, but I found solution from karate documentation with.

```
queries: [{type: TERM, match: EQUAL, field: "fieldOne", value: "<id>"},
      {type: TERM, match: EQUAL, field: "fieldTwo", value: null}]
```

enclose id inside query text in angle brackets <> and then replace id inside query with id stored in variable id by calling

```
* replace query.id = id
```